# UISearchController's init(searchResultsController: UIViewController?) crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchcontroller

Calling `UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` in a new ViewController's `viewDidLoad()` crashes with `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x185d73080)` (aka, some nil optional was unwrapped).

If I try to execute the code in another new project / playground, it works without crashing.

Having also created a custom `UISearchController` and having it debugged by breakpoints, it lead me to the `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` method and then it crashed. It might be linked.

**I must mention that calling the simple `init()` does not crash my app.**

Exact example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
}
```

[image: Crash]

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: Did that right now. Same thing.

Comment: And you´re sure it´s crashing on that particular row?

Comment: Yes. I am using a breakpoint right at the row and after it gets over the line it crashes. The rest of the VC is empty.

Comment: I think you have an issue on something else. probably some outlet. `UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` should not crash. If you want to, zip your project and upload it to Dropbox/Google drive and paste the link here and I´ll try to find the error for you.

Comment: I have had created an empty VC, it has only this line in `viewDidLoad()`. I can't zip the project because it's confidential. It's the shittiest bug ever. Another idea is that it worked (some time before), but when today I checked the screen again, it prompted with this crash. Maybe it's a bug regarding project configurations, Cocoapods intersecting functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, but it's incredible. I created a new project and added files one by one to see which one interferes with my code.

Seems like I had an extension:

```
    @IBInspectable var paddingRight: CGFloat {
    get {
        return rightView!.frame.size.width
    }
    set {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.size.height))
        rightView = paddingView
        rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

And that `rightView!` crashed my app randomly without error.

Lesson learned, extension can provoke that error.